# When I add product from backend I got this

Tags: product, 404-page, product-page, magento2.2.6

I am using Magento 2.2.6

When I add product from backend I got page like shown in below image.

Is it any known issue in Magento 2.2.6 or any cache related issue?

[image]

Comment: I remember getting this when using some cms block widget on the page. Make sure the widgets you have on the product page don't have errors in them.

Comment: no there is no any cms block or widget  on this page